# Spivak, Chapter 20, Problem 11: Using Taylor's Theorem Instead of L'Hôpital´s Rule to compute limit.

Tags: calculus, integration, derivatives, solution-verification, taylor-expansion

The following is a problem from Chapter 20 of Spivak's *Calculus*

> 11. Calculations of this sort may be used to evaluate limits that we might otherwise try to find through laborious use of l'Hopital's Rule.
>     Find the following
>
> (a) $\lim\limits_{x\to 0}
>  \frac{e^x-1-x-\frac{1}{2}x^2}{x-\sin{x}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}
>  \frac{N(x)}{D(x)}$
>
> Hint: First find $P_{3,0,N}(x)$ and $P_{3,0,D}(x)$ for the numerator
> and denominator $N(x)$ and $D(x)$.

"Calculations of this sort" refers to the previous problem $10$ in which we compute Taylor polynomials of functions $f+g$, $f\cdot g$, and $f\circ g$, using formulas derived in problem $9$.

Here is the solution manual solution

> $$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{N(x)}{D(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to
>  0}\frac{\frac{1}{6}x^3+R_{3,0,N}(x)}{\frac{1}{6}x^3+R_{3,0,D}(x)}=\lim\limits_{x\to
>  0}\frac{\frac{1}{6}+\frac{R_{3,0,N}(x)}{x^3}}{\frac{1}{6}+\frac{R_{3,0,D}(x)}{x^3}}=1$$
>
> since the limits involving $R$ terms are $0$

My question is about the intermediate steps in this proof. Here is my attempt at writing them out.

Using Taylor's Theorem, we can easily see that

$$N(x)=P_{3,0,N}(x)+R_{3,0,N}(x)$$

$$=\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{e^t}{4!}x^4, t\in (0,x)$$

$$D(x)=P_{3,0,D}(x)+R_{3,0,N}(x)$$

$$=\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{(-\sin{u})}{4!}x^4,u\in (0,x)$$

Therefore, we have

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0}
 \frac{e^x-1-x-\frac{1}{2}x^2}{x-\sin{x}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0}
 \frac{N(x)}{D(x)}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{e^t}{4!}x^4}{\frac{x^3}{3!}+\frac{(-\sin{u})}{4!}x^4}$$

$$=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{\frac{1}{6}+\frac{e^t x}{4!}}{\frac{1}{6}-\frac{x\sin{(u)}}{4!}}$$

$$=1$$

**Are these intermediate steps correct?**

Seems like this was all a lot more work than applying L'Hopital directly to the original limit.

$$\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1-x-\frac{1}{2}x^2}{x-\sin{x}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x-1}{\sin{x}}=\lim\limits_{x\to 0} \frac{e^x}{\cos{x}}=1$$

Comment: well, if you know Taylor's series for a few important functions, $e^x = 1 + x + \frac{x^2}{2}  + \frac{x^3}{6}  + O(x^4)$  and $\sin x = x - \frac{x^3}{6}  + O(x^5)$  where capital   $O$  means absolute value  no bigger than a constant times...

Answer (score 1):

Your argumentation is sound. L'Hopital and Taylor are equivalent here, clearly the derivatives of the nominator and the denominator have to be computed, and evaluated at the limit point, in this case $0$, until (at least) one of the two differs from $0$. I would agree, however, that it is reasonable to be aware of both l'Hopital's and Taylor's perspective.

Your intermediate steps are also correct, if you used $u=u(x)$ and $t=t(x)$, both in the interval enclosing $0$ and $x$ (which is $(x,0)$ for negative $x$!), as functions of $x$ as given by the Lagrange form of the remainder.